# Sum currency column based on status?

Tags: mysql, crosstab

I have a crosstabl query that works great summing all records depending on a certain record status [Active, Ended etc etc]

```
Select
  c.ReferralName,
  Sum((d.CaseStatusName) = 'Active') As Active,
  Sum((d.CaseStatusName) = 'Completed') As Completed,
  Sum((d.CaseStatusName) = 'Submitted') As Submitted,
  Count(b.CaseID) As Total,
  Sum(b.LeadCost) As Cost
From
  tblcontacts a Inner Join
  tblcases b On a.ContactID = b.ContactID Inner Join
  tblreferral c On c.RefferalID = a.ContactReferrelSource Inner Join
  tblcasestatus d On d.CaseStatusID = b.CaseStatusName
Group By
  c.ReferralName With Rollup
```

This works great but I now want to also run a query that replaces the Sum of d.CaseStatusName with Sum of b.LeadCost but cannot find a way to achieve it!

I think what I need is to have Sum of b.LeadCost if d.CaseStatusName='Active', etc etc

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select
  c.ReferralName,
  Sum(CASE WHEN (d.CaseStatusName) = 'Active'    THEN b.LeadCost ELSE 0 END) As Active,
  Sum(CASE WHEN (d.CaseStatusName) = 'Completed' THEN b.LeadCost ELSE 0 END) As Completed,
  Sum(CASE WHEN (d.CaseStatusName) = 'Submitted' THEN b.LeadCost ELSE 0 END) As Submitted,
  Count(b.CaseID) As Total,
  Sum(b.LeadCost) As Cost
From
  tblcontacts a Inner Join
  tblcases b On a.ContactID = b.ContactID Inner Join
  tblreferral c On c.RefferalID = a.ContactReferrelSource Inner Join
  tblcasestatus d On d.CaseStatusID = b.CaseStatusName
Group By
  c.ReferralName With Rollup
```

Comment: -Many many thanks Tom, that's exactly what I needed and does the job perfectly. Really appreciate your time & knowledge.

Comment: No problem.  I have to do that kind of thing fairly frequently so I have it in the front of my mind.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your requirement, but it seems that you may want to use `CASE` to check for the condition based on `d.CaseStatusName`:

```
SELECT
  c.ReferralName,
  CASE
    WHEN d.CaseStatusName = 'Active'
      THEN b.LeadCost
    ELSE 'SomethingElse'
  END AS casecolumn
...
```